# What is the maximum size SD card supported by the Canon IXUS 50?

Tags: canon, memory-card, sdcard, memory-card-size

Am using a 2GB SD-card with a Canon IXUS 50/SD400 Digital ELPH. I tried a 4GB card but got an error saying the card is "locked". The card is not write protected, and works fine in a couple of other devices. The menu option to format the card is not active.

I have not been able to find any useful info on the web regarding maximum size of card, or file system requirements etc. The 4GB card was formatted in Win 7 with default settings (FAT).

Does anybody know the maximum size of SD-card that the IXUS 50 supports? And/or the exact requirements on the formatting? There are something like eight different types of FAT, I believe.

Comment: The storage cards must be formatted in the camera. Try please and add the result in question.

Comment: The format option is greyed out, presumably because of the error. I'm pretty sure it is not necessary to format it in the camera, it just needs to be the right format. I am not sure exactly how picky this particular camera is.

Comment: See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SD_card#Comparison). SD cards accept FAT12 or FAT16.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this](https://www.memorycow.co.uk/digital-camera/canon/ixus-series/canon-ixus-50-digital-camera) site the maximum size of cards for this camera is 2GB. So you should stay with this size. And I do not think there is option to use bigger SD cards.

And the best way to format the card is to do it in camera.

Comment: As pointed out by @xenoid, FAT16 can only support up to 2Gb.